# Installing windows software on linux

Tags: software-installation, windows

I want to install a windows software on ubuntu 20.04 without using a VM.

Specifically, I want to install the Windows 3D Builder.

Is there any way of doing it?

Answer (score 2):

Using a VM is unfortunately the only way to run 3D Builder under Linux. 3D Builder is a [UWP](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/universal-application-platform-guide) app, so it is unsupported by Wine.

I suggest trying [Blender](https://www.blender.org/) which is free and supports 3D Builder's file formats. If you're insistent on using 3D Builder, I recommend using [VMWare](https://www.vmware.com/go/downloadplayer), which has relatively good performance and is easy to set up.

Answer (score 0):

[Wine](https://www.winehq.org/) provides compatibility layer for running Windows applications on Linux. It can't provide 100 % compatibility, but generally you should be able to run most of Windows applications.

Wine community maintains [database of supported applications](https://appdb.winehq.org/), but I wasn't able to find "Windows 3D Builder" there, so I recommend just trying to install and run it, Wine should be available in your distribution repositories and after installing it just run `wine xyz.exe` and see what happens.